# Auto-Layout Guide: UIImagePickerController W/ Custom Overlay Won't Rotate

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a UIImagePickerController with a custom overlay. In the nib file for the overlay, I set UI constraints for two different size classes `wc hR` for portrait and `wC hC` for landscape. Each constraint is installed for the correct size class.

However, it won't rotate when I turn the camera landscape. I set up my `UIImagePickerController` like so:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];


    _activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        ipc.showsCameraControls = NO;

        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SnapItCameraView" owner:self options:nil];
        self.overlayView.frame = ipc.cameraOverlayView.frame;
        ipc.cameraOverlayView = self.overlayView;
        self.overlayView = nil;

        CGSize screenBounds = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;

        CGFloat cameraAspectRatio = 4.0f/3.0f;

        CGFloat camViewHeight = screenBounds.width * cameraAspectRatio;
        CGFloat scale = screenBounds.height / camViewHeight;
        ipc.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, (screenBounds.height - camViewHeight) / 2.0);
        ipc.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(ipc.cameraViewTransform, scale, scale);

        ipc.showsCameraControls = NO;
        ipc.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
        ipc.allowsEditing = YES;
        [ipc setAllowsEditing:YES];


    }else{
        ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    }

    [self presentViewController:ipc animated:YES completion:nil];
    [_activityIndicator stopAnimating];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Apple's docs:

> **Important**
>
> The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only.

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller?language=objc